# Unable to set apache php.ini path

Tags: php, apache

I know there have been dozens of topics written about this, but still after reading many of them, I can't get this to work. I need to set the php.ini path in Apache server running on Windows.
part of my httpd.conf file:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "C:/php"
LoadModule php5_module "C:/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll"
```

The PHP itself runs fine, but when i call `phpinfo();`, I still get this:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   C:\Windows
```

I have searched the config several times and this directory isn't even mentioned there, so I am really confused now. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you tell Apache to reload the configuration?

Comment: I restarted the whole apache, do I need to reload the config explicitely?

Comment: Restarting Apache reloads the configuration.

Comment: Then yes... I restarted the Apache using some control panel (showing in systray as Monitor Apache Services), so I guess the configuration did reload. Still no change in php.ini path status